# Remove jQuery hover effect

Tags: javascript, html, hover

When mouse hovers on a link, suppose effect `X` takes place. 
How can I restore the original when the mouse has moved away?

For instance, I tried to modify the link-behavior using javascript. The link changes on hovering mouse, but how can I revert the change?

HTML code:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li id="a1"><a href="#">original link 1</a></li>
    <li id="a2"><a href="#">hover link 1</a></li>
    <li id="b1"><a href="#">original link 1</a></li>
    <li id="b2"><a href="#">hover link 1</a></li>
    <li id="c1"><a href="#">original link 1</a></li>
    <li id="c2"><a href="#">hover link 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript Code:

```
$("#nav a li").hover(function () {
     $('#' +this.id.charAt(0)+"1").hide();
});
```

Comment: Your markup is *absolutely* invalid. `<li>` elements should be direct children of list elements like `<ul>`, `<ol>` *only*.

Comment: @xan did you read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) for the `.hover()` function?

Comment: @VisioN: Sorry, I was in a bit of hurry. Check my code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 $("#nav a li").on('hover', function () {
   //mousehover
 } , function(){
   //mouseout
 } );
```

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS instead, after correcting your HTML markup. This will give you better performance, less code, and is more "proper" because visual details should be left to CSS.

```
#nav li:hover {
  display: none;
}
```

**Update:** After trying to understand your markup further, I see better what you are trying to do. You seem to want to hide the next `<li>` element. In that case, use a CSS adjacency selector:

```
#nav li:hover + li {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: +1 for a different suggestion, but css alone may not fulfill the requirements when he hovers over the link.  Granted, the code example leaves much up to the imagination.

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote is equivalent to `$(selector).on("mouseenter mouseleave", handlerInOut);`

Use valid markup...

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">hover link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">hover link 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

JQuery

```
$("#nav a li").hover(function () {
     $('#' +this.id.charAt(0)+"1").hide();
 }, function() {
     $('#' +this.id.charAt(0)+"1").show();
});
```

from the jQuery API docs: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

> Calling $(selector).hover(handlerIn, handlerOut) is shorthand for:
>   $(selector).mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);

Answer (score 0):

Use mouseover and mouseout [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) insted of hover